# Needing an ExtJS bug workaround

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a web application that uses Ext-JS 2.2. In a certain component, we have an empty toolbar that we are trying to add a button to using

```
myPanel.getTopToolbar().insertButton(0, [...array of buttons...]);
```

However, in IE6/7 this fails because of lines 20241-20242 in ext-all-debug.js:

```
var td = document.createElement("td");
this.tr.insertBefore(td, this.tr.childNodes[index]);
```

Since "this.tr.childNodes([0])" does not yet exist in IE, this fails with "Invalid argument".

THE REAL QUESTION:
Can I, using CSS similar to the below add a child to every toolbar <tr> so that this.tr.childNodes[0] is found:

```
div.x-toolbar tr:after { content: " "; }
```

I totally realize this is a hack, but for legal reasons I cannot change any Javascript, not even to add an empty button ({}) to each toolbar. Major kudos to anyone that can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think there was a CSS-only solution.

For the record, I ended up injecting javascript into the page that overrides the Ext.Toolbar prototype for the insertButton() function to check for the existance of "this.tr.childNodes([0])" and default to addButton() if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

What I've had to do in the past was include an empty toolbar in my element config:

tbar:[]

Then (and only after the element has completely rendered) use the .add() method for injecting buttons.

Order of events will get you every time. It takes a while to get a handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing is adding to a empty panel

```
 myPanel.getTopToolbar().add(buttons etc);
```

Or

```
 myPanel.getTopToolbar().addButton(..);
```

Either should work.  It looks like purpose of insertButton is for putting a button within a non-empty toolbar.

Comment: Shouldn't insertButtons gracefully fall back to addButtons in case of none? I think we must consider this as a minor bug in ExtJs...

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into adding the button after the panel has been rendered?  Maybe something like:

```
myPanel.on('render', function() {
   this.getTopToolbar().insertButton(0, [...array of buttons...]);
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue wasn't timing. Turns out that the insertButton function only works if there is something in the Toolbar already.